# Do I have to close stdout after use subprocess.run()

Tags: python

I am trying to create subprocess to remove python a package and return stdout and stderr. I do following but I wonder is it safe to use? Today I faced `/bin/bash: resource temporarily unavailable` error while I am using. And when I do `ps ux` I saw lots of bin/bash process.

I think that function cause lots of bash terminal in the background. How should I safely close the subprocess after I got `stdout` and `stderr`? Documentation [says](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) run method is the recommended way.

```
def run_subprocess_command(process_command):
    response = {"stdout": "", "stderr": "", "exception": ""}
    try:
        plugin_install_feedback.send(
            sender="", message="Package install starting..")

        p = subprocess.run(process_command,
                           universal_newlines=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           timeout=180)

        response["stdout"] = p.stdout
        response["stderr"] = p.stderr
        return response

    except Exception as err:
        response["exception"] = err
        return response
```

Comment: I think `subprocess.run` takes the `close_fds=True` argument, and will handle that for you.

Comment: @torxed - `close_fds` is about what happens to file handles in the child processes. When a subprocess runs, any file the parent happens to have open is also open in the child. With `close_fds=True` (now the default in python), those other files are closed in the child. 99% of the time, that's what you want.

Comment: `subprocess.run` runs the program to completion, closes the pipes and does a wait to make sure the process is removed from the process table. You don't need to do anything else.